# Oracle timestamp comparison issue in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below query is returning null on running in Oracle

```
SELECT MAX(ROW_CREATION_TMSTP) 
FROM RULES_REPOSITORY 
WHERE rule_cd = 'LCC12G' 
  AND (TO_CHAR(expiration_dt,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') > TO_CHAR(current_timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

I have a single row in my table with the following values of columns
**rule_cd = LCC12G

expiration_dt = '10-JUN-13 03.51.12.000000000 AM'

ROW_CREATION_TMSTP = 10-APR-13 03.51.12.000000000 AM**

By looking at the values it should return value of ROW_CREATION_TMSTP given above but it is not returning.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Char Comparision does the problem. Just compare as it is.. don't type cast it.. i mean "TO_CHAR(expiration_dt,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') > TO_CHAR(current_timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))"

Comment: It's totally useless to convert a date to a character value before comparing it.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX(ROW_CREATION_TMSTP)
FROM RULES_REPOSITORY
WHERE rule_cd = 'LCC12G'
AND expiration_dt > current_timestamp;
```

Will do good..!

Comment: It is good idea to trunc both dates to compare: ...trunc(expiration_dt) > trunc(current_timestamp);